# How can I fill missing values if they meet a certain value in the dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a dataset with about 2400 rows and some rows are missing a value as you can see in the following example:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| Name | Year | Value | Name2 | Value2 |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| A    | 2010 |    10 |       |    ... |
| A    | 2011 |    10 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2012 |    12 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2013 |    14 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2014 |     9 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2015 |    13 |       |    ... |
| B    | 2010 |     8 |       |    ... |
| B    | 2011 |    10 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2012 |    11 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2013 |    12 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2014 |    10 |       |    ... |
| B    | 2015 |    11 |       |    ... |
| C    | 2010 |    11 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2011 |    10 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2012 |     9 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2013 |     8 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2014 |    10 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2015 |    10 |       |    ... |
| ...  |  ... |   ... | ...   |    ... |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I would like to fill up the missing values in column "Name 2" with the correct values, so it looks like this:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| Name | Year | Value | Name2 | Value2 |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| A    | 2010 |    10 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2011 |    10 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2012 |    12 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2013 |    14 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2014 |     9 | AA    |    ... |
| A    | 2015 |    13 | AA    |    ... |
| B    | 2010 |     8 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2011 |    10 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2012 |    11 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2013 |    12 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2014 |    10 | BB    |    ... |
| B    | 2015 |    11 | BB    |    ... |
| C    | 2010 |    11 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2011 |    10 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2012 |     9 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2013 |     8 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2014 |    10 | CC    |    ... |
| C    | 2015 |    10 | CC    |    ... |
| ...  |  ... |   ... | ...   |    ... |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I already tried the `fill()`command but did not succeed. **Filling the value with the latest non-NA value does not work since it would sometimes add the wrong values (e.g. B 2010 would be filled with AA)!**

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please use `dput()`-output to paste your data.

Comment: How do you decide the fillers? If they're the latest non-NA, look at the link provided above.

Comment: The latest non-NA does not work since in this case the first observation for B would be filled with AA.